# R pivot_longer(): tidyr wide to long manipulation reverse pivot summary to individual values

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying to manipulate a wide table which represents the per cent of each household composition type within two towns to a long-form table (basically, a reverse of a pivot table).

In the long table, I would like each row to represent the household composition value for one household. So, the number of rows for each combination depends on the values provided e.g. 18 rows of (town.a, singles), 8 rows of (town.b, singles etc.). However, I just can't seem to figure out how to do this expansion based on the values in each *Town* column.

I have a data.frame() that looks like this:

```
household.data <- data.frame(household.composition= c("Singles","Couples", "Families", "Single Parents", "Sharers"),
                             town.a =c(18,29,41,3,3),
                             town.b =c(8,37,48,9,3))
```

[image]

The values under the *Town A* and *Town B* columns represent the per cent makeup of each household composition within each town.

The goal is to get from this wide summary format to a long format which multiplies the value in the *Household Composition* column by the numeric value within the *Town A* and *Town B* columns. So each row would represent the household composition value for one household. For example:

[image]

Again, I know that there must be a way to do this using the spread/gather or pivot function in tidyR. However, I just can't seem to figure out how to do this expansion given that I would like the number of rows to correspond with the per cent value.

Comment: Do you want there to be for example, 18 rows of (town.a, singles), 8 rows of (town.b, singles etc.? So, the number of rows for each combination depends on the values provided?

Comment: Hi, yes that is exactly what I am after! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the data in long format and use `uncount` to replicate rows.

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(household.data, cols = -household.composition) %>% uncount(value)

# A tibble: 199 x 2
#   household.composition name  
#   <chr>                 <chr> 
# 1 Singles               town.a
# 2 Singles               town.a
# 3 Singles               town.a
# 4 Singles               town.a
# 5 Singles               town.a
# 6 Singles               town.a
# 7 Singles               town.a
# 8 Singles               town.a
# 9 Singles               town.a
#10 Singles               town.a
# … with 189 more rows
```

Comment: Oh what a great function,  I haven't come across uncount() thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can work as follows:

1. Convert the data from wide to long format using `tidyr::pivot_longer`
2. Use `lapply` to apply the `rep`-licate function based on the number of times in `value`
3. Since `lapply` gives results as list, use `dplyr::bind_rows` to bind them into a dataframe
4. Remove the `value` column to get the desired output

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 household.data %>% 
   pivot_longer(-household.composition, names_to = "town") %>% 
   lapply(rep, .$value) %>% 
   bind_rows() %>%
   select(-value)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you @HNSKD :)

Comment: You can save a line with `purrr::map_df` in place of `lapply` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
setNames(within(
  reshape(
    household.data,
    direction = "long",
    varying = grepl("town", names(household.data)),
    timevar = "town_type",
    times = NULL,
    idvar = !(grepl("town", names(household.data))),
    new.row.names = 1:(nrow(household.data) * length(grepl(
      "town", names(household.data)
    )))
  ),
  {
    rm(town)
  }
), c("household.composition", "town"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution

```r
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(household.data),id.vars = "household.composition")[rep(1:.N,value),.( household.composition,variable)]
```